# Material UI color palette - how to use colors prefixed with "A"

Tags: material-ui, material-design

If I import a colour from material ui as follows:

import blue from '@material-ui/core/colors/blue';

I can use it as follows for the colors in the palette that do not include "A":

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: { main: blue[100] },
```

How can I access the colors that are prefixed with "A"?

For example, #[82b1ff](https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=1&view.right=0&primary.color=2962FF&secondary.color=82B1FF) is in blue - with reference A100.  When I try:

primary: { main: blue[A100] },

I get an error saying A100 is not defined.

What do I need to be able to use the colors that are defined with an A?

Comment: try `blue['A100']`

Comment: no prob. for more information, you could have a look at this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Accessing_properties)

Comment: thanks again. Which bit of that documentation is relevant? if a number works for one set of color references, why wouldn't a string work for another? I'd love to know how you made the leap from that documentation to the solution to this question. I have a hard time making sense of coding documentation and I think figuring out how to find the link between that doc and this problem is the fundamental problem.